# How can i parse code from URL in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, parsing, uri

I have next uri:

> https://91c2ee0d-05ff-4611-2192-8472eabe98f1.example.org/redirect#code=d5215173-2be3-4491-bf2a-d9d039a50e97&id_token=eyJhbGciOiJQU

How i can parse my code?

```
d5215173-2be3-4491-bf2a-d9d039a50e97
```

I tried to do smth like this:

```
val uri: Uri = Uri.parse(url) 
val code: String = uri.getQueryParameter("code").toString()
```

But it doesn't work for me.

Comment: the part after the hash sign is a fragment identifier, so the `getQueryParameter` method won't work. You can use the `getFragment` method to get the full string after `#` and then extract the code out of it

Comment: Everything after the `#` would be in `uri.fragment`. I don't think the `Uri` class will help you parse that any further, but you could do it manually from there. Or you could cheat and replace that `#` with a `?` before passing it to `Uri.parse()`, which should cause it to parse that as a query string, then `uri.getQueryParameter("code")` would work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Right now i solved this problem with next solution:

```
val url: String = Uri.parse(url).toString()
var code = ""
if (url.contains("#code=")) {
    code = url.substring(url.indexOf("#code=") + 6)
    if (code.contains("&")) {
        code = code.split("&")[0]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you could do it with a Regex:

```
val url = Uri.parse(url).toString()

val matcher = Pattern.compile("#code=.+&").matcher(url)
val code = if (matcher.find())
    url.slice(matcher.start() + 6 until matcher.end() - 1) else ""
```